# Using doorkeeper on a subdirectory seems to cause problems with oauth/token route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, omniauth, doorkeeper

I have a client and provider set up with doorkeeper and omniauth-oauth2 based on the code from these repo:

- https://github.com/jagthedrummer/so_auth
- https://github.com/jagthedrummer/so_auth_provider
- https://github.com/jagthedrummer/so_auth_client

I've updated and customized the code a bit, but the basic concept is the same. [The provider](https://github.com/jagthedrummer/so_auth_provider) is a Rails app using doorkeeper, [the client](https://github.com/jagthedrummer/so_auth_client) is another Rails app using [so_auth](https://github.com/jagthedrummer/so_auth) as a gem to configure the oauth interaction. It works fine in development, but I have the provider on a subdirectory in production. Here's the simplified request log:

### Client

```
05.930552 Started GET "/private"
05.947759 Redirected to https://example.com/auth/stm?origin=https://example.com/private
05.965877 Started GET "/auth/stm?origin=https://example.com/private"
```

### Provider

```
05.993805 Started GET "/provider/oauth/authorize?client_id=449ecb&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fauth%2Fstm%2Fcallback&response_type=code"
06.021069 Redirected to https://example.com/auth/stm/callback?code=7fdbc57c
```

### Client

```
06.043829 Started GET "/auth/stm/callback?code=7fdbc57c51"
08.997899 Started POST "/oauth/token"
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/oauth/token")
```

The problem seems to be that it's looking for `/oauth/token` on the client app rather than the provider app, because the url should be at `provider/oauth/token`. Prior to that POST request, the `GET /auth/stm/callback` request should be going to the `UserSessionsController#create` action, but no matter what debug code I put in there, it never gets called. It just goes straight to the following `POST /oauth/token` request. Here's the route:

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback', :to => 'so_auth/user_sessions#create'
```

And the action:

```
def create
omniauth = env['omniauth.auth']

user = User.find_by_id(omniauth['uid'])
if not user
  # New user registration
  user = User.new
  user.id = omniauth['uid']
end
user.email = omniauth['info']['email'] if user.respond_to?(:email)
user.save

session[:user_id] = user.id

flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in"
redirect_to request.env['omniauth.origin'] || root_path
end
```

I can't figure out how to get between the `GET` and `POST` requests in the second half of the client log. If I set up a logger in the application controller to log the controller `action_name`, it runs on all other controller actions except the `create` action I'm trying to figure out. Why is it jumping from `GET "/auth/stm/callback"` to `POST "/oauth/token"` without running the `UserSessionsController#create` action? And core question still being, why is it going to `/oauth/token` instead of `/provider/oauth/token`?